# Android - Intent working improperly

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created an Intent which opens link for the MX Player app in google play.

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Get Now",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    Intent mx = new Intent(
                                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    mx.setData(Uri
                                            .parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en"));
                                    startActivity(mx);
                                }
                            });
```

The problem is when the google play is already opened in background and the user presses the button to open the link, the app force closes.
Any solution is welcomed.